# Distribute files on cluster creation with Spark on EC2

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I am working with *Spark* on *Amazon*'s *EC2* infrastructure. I need to distribute and send a custom file (a native library, in my case) onto all the worker nodes before the execution of my *Spark* application. I am looking for something similar to the bootstrapping functionality offered by *Amazon*'s *Elastic MapReduce (EMR)*, with which the developers can run a custom script on every nodes at the boot phase.

So far, I have used the `copy-dir` script provided by *Spark* (located on the `spark-ec2` folder) that copies a determined file into all the nodes available in the cluster, which work as follows:

Imagine a native library (`myLib.so`) that needs to be present in all nodes. The first step would be to locate the file in the exact directory we want to propagate through the cluster. After that, we could run the `copy-dir` script as follows:

```
spark-ec2/ > sh copy-dir my/file/location/myLib.so
```

However, this approach can only be used once the cluster has been created, and I would like to know if any bootstrapping possibility exists.

Comment: The `--user-data` option in `spark-ec2` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Look into sc.addFile(). This can be used to distribute files to all the worker nodes

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not looking for what you mention. Instead, I need to distribute a file before the Spark execution (at the cluster creation), for other purposes that do not include the Spark application.

Answer (score 0):

In order to distribute the code from master to worker nodes/slaves
Use the copy-dir script and mention the path to the file/directory that one wants to distribute.
Example - If I have a wordcount.py file in /root/ directory - Following code distributes the file to worker nodes / slaves

```
sudo /root/spark-ec2/copy-dir /root/wordcount.py 
RSYNC'ing /root/wordcount.py to slaves...
ec2-54-175-163-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Chaitanya, but The solution you talk about is already included in the question.

Comment: Ah yes - Another way of executing the same script. Right